# Please, Help me understand one phrase he says

Tags: listening

I'm watching Tony Robbins video and there's a phrase I can't understand in the whole video. Can anyone help me out? Here's the link
https://youtu.be/kVKZSatIEng?t=35m55s
He says "If you gonna master something ...blah-blah..where you don't think about it and just do it." What does he say next at 36:05? Master is .... I can't get what he says in the next one. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He says "Mastery is tying your shoes", as in 'once you've done it a lot of times, it won't be hard at all, you can do it without thinking about it'.

Answer (score 1):

> Mastery is tying your shoes.  Most of you can do this, chew on some gum, send a text simultaneously.  Not some people -- some people get their tongue out while they're doing it (but) you get the idea.

Robbins uses the example of tying your shoes, chewing gum, sending a text to describe how people can *master* a task so well that they can do it without thinking, even do them all at the same time.

Comment: Thank you!!! He speaks so fast and masterfully chews his own words)